# Repeating a group of textviews in android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

i want to get a page with a group of text views repeated..i have fetched the data from the database.But i dont know about making the text fields and repeating it till the number of records fetched from db.I have fetched all data needed.![enter image description here][1]Can anyone help me?

my xml page

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Refillhist" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:text="Order no:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pref_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/order_no"
        android:layout_below="@+id/order_no"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="pref no:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_dat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pref_no"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pref_no"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Order date:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deli_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/order_dat"
        android:layout_below="@+id/order_dat"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:text="Delivery date:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deli_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/deli_date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deli_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:text="Delivery status:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deli_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/deli_date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deli_status"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Delivery Time:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i want this to repeat for different values fetched from db.

Comment: Use ListView and write proper adapter for it

Answer (score 0):

A [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) (or any other other view that are extending from a [AbsListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html)) is the most appropriate widget for what you are trying to achieve.